# User location is not displayed on the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I am developing an application that is based on GPS/user location using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3mKhMkdUFk). The idea is when the user opens second activity (by clicking the button) it should locate the device on the map and update it every second, here is the activity code:

```
public class MapLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maplocation);
    initMap();
}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get current location!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);
    }
}}
```

and here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/_fff">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here are the necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

The map works fine, however the problem is that it wont show my device on the map (my location), in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3mKhMkdUFk) it works. I'm running the application on the device and emulator and the results are the same, map is working fine but my location is not displayed on the map. Can someone explain to me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your emulator have GPS/locations on eg:https://gyazo.com/577bd3f0c2fb8a9de6b8d1993c7ecc9c

Comment: It is on, both on emulator and my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crucial mistake that you can see right away is that you are missing the `setLocationEnabbled(true)` method.

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onMapReady", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    } else {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}

 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location is disabled, turn it on in your settings,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            mMap.clear();
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            mCurrLocation = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .zoom(11)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }else{
             Toast.makeText(this, "LastLocation is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...yes, i forgot that, embarrassingly. Thank you :)